# What could be the possible cause of the Netty Decompression Exception: CRC value mismatch?

Tags: compression, netty, reactor-netty

I have a service that consumes a flux of integers produced by another microservice through a WebClient (org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient), and from time to time encounters below exception. What could be the possible cause of it?

```
io.netty.handler.codec.compression.DecompressionException: CRC value mismatch. Expected: 3453327130, Got: 1861228094
 at io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibDecoder.verifyCrc(JdkZlibDecoder.java:387) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibDecoder.readGZIPFooter(JdkZlibDecoder.java:365) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.compression.JdkZlibDecoder.decode(JdkZlibDecoder.java:219) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:503) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:281) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.embedded.EmbeddedChannel.writeInbound(EmbeddedChannel.java:343) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.decode(HttpContentDecoder.java:254) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.decodeContent(HttpContentDecoder.java:161) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.decode(HttpContentDecoder.java:150) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.decode(HttpContentDecoder.java:47) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:326) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:300) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1478) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1227) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1274) ~[netty-handler-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:503) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:281) ~[netty-codec-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931) ~[netty-transport-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:502) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:407) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.43.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.43.Final.jar!/:4.1.43.Final]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
```

Answer (score 0):

So the possible cause could be that the data packets are corrupted before arriving to the client side for decompression. There should be nothing wrong with Netty.